# Solve equation of mean field theory with Scilab

Tags: scilab

i try to evaluate the equation =tanh(zJ/k_B T)
using newton rampson method. when i run the program i got an error:

> plot: Wrong size for input arguments #2 and #3: Incompatible
>   dimensions.

and a blank graph. plz help me out whats the problem in my code.

```
z=4\\ no. of nearest neighbours 

m=1;//value of J/K

T=[0.1:0.1:8]\\value of temerature

s(1)=-0.5;//initial value

n=100;\\no. of iterations


for  i=1:n \\ running of for loop
    f= s(i)-tanh(z*m*s(i)./T);//equation of mean field theory
    l=derivat(f); // derivative of f
    s(i+1)=s(i)-(f/l); // implementation of newton rampson method
    if abs(s(i+1)-s(i)) <= 10^-8 then
    end

    s(i)=s(i+1)

    i=i+1;//increment in i values

end

plot(T,s,'.r')
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand after reading about equation of mean field theory is that you want to solve s=tanh(z*m*s/T) for different values of T then plot s versus T. Here is how you can do it in Scilab (no need to code Newton's method yourself you can use fsolve (see the help page of this function)

```
function out = eq(s,T)
    out = s-tanh(z*m*s/T) 
end

z=4;
m=1;
T=[0.1:0.1:8];

for i=1:length(T)
   s(i) = fsolve(-0.5,list(eq,T(i)))
end

clf
plot(T,s)
xlabel T
ylabel s
```

[image]